# Exit mitmdump from a python script

Tags: python, mitmproxy

How can I exit mitmpdump command from a script?

Tried `sys.exit(0)` but it doesn't finish the process mitmpdump, it only stops filtering.

This is  my script

```
"""
This script adds a filter.
Usage:
  mitmdump -s "script.py"
"""
import sys
from mitmproxy import flowfilter

class Filter:
  def __init__(self):
    self.filter = flowfilter.parse("~h my_filter")

  def response(self, flow):
    if flowfilter.match(self.filter, flow):
      print("Flow matches filter:")
      print(flow.request.headers["my_filter"])
      sys.exit(0)

def start():
  return Filter()
```

Comment: Try to add `from mitmproxy import ctx` and replace `sys.exit(0)` with `flow.kill(ctx.master)`. If that works, I will add an answer.

Comment: mitmdump says: `flow.kill(ctx.master) ... TypeError: kill() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is working for me on v9.0.1

```
from mitmproxy import ctx
ctx.master.shutdown() #place this in the code where you want to trigger the shutdown
```